# Unexpected token => in Javascript for chrome v41 and ie11

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the quick way to fix the error

> Unexpected token => .

I wrote below code and it only runs in higher version of chrome but not on lower version and ie11.

```
var result = aIndice.filter(obj => {
        return obj.Type === "E"
})
```

Comment: Ideally, integrate Babel into your build process to transpile ES6+ syntax into ES5 automatically. Lazy but not-scalable solution is to use a standard function instead

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: Older versions of browsers, and also IE, do not support arrow functions.

Comment: Chrome 41? The current version of Chrome is 68. Don't support Chrome 41, mark is as a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an arrow function `obj => { }` which will not work in Internet Explorer 11. You need to either use tools like [Babel](http://babeljs.io) to compile your ES6 code to ES5, or simply avoid using any modern features.

You can also write your function like this:

```
var result = aIndice.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.Type === "E"
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I am actually looking to avoid using modern features and rewrite the functions. But how do i write functions where validations are required   var erorrWorkorders = result.map(a => a.MessageV1);
                erorrWorkorders = erorrWorkorders.filter(MessageV1 => MessageV1.length > 6);

Comment: `result.map(a => a.MessageV1); ` would be the same as `result.map(function(a) { return a.MessageV1; });`

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions are an [es2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#7th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015) feature, therefore they will not run on older browsers.
Some features can be implemented by using different polyfills like [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/), but arrow functions are a language expression and thus can't be polyfilled.
You can tell what features are available in what browsers by using [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20functions).

The solution to this problem is transpiling the code with a tool like [babel](https://babeljs.io/).
To transpile your script with babel, you will need to install [npm and node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), and then initiate an npm project:

```
$ npm init
```

And install the dependencies we need, the [babel-cli](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-cli) and a preset for it to use [babel-preset-env](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env).

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env
```

Now you need a settings file for babel, you can define your target browsers there using browserlist, so create a file named ".babelrc" and in it write:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "ie": "11",
        "chrome": 41
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Add a new npm script to package.json (created by calling npm init)
"script.js" is the source script, and "script-transpiled.js" is the output script.

```
"scripts": {
  "transpile": "babel script.js --o script-transpiled.js"
}
```

And call

```
npm run transpile
```

Now your script will be transpiled into a new file `script-transpiled.js` and you can run it the targeted browsers.
To work with a large scale project it is recommended to use [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).